# Android - Set font in other language

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How can I set custom font to editText in Android? I use this code

```
    etPlace = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPlace);
    etPlace.setTypeface(tf);
```

It can work with English language. But if I type in Thai language, it will become to HEX. I tried to remove setTypeface code but it can't solve. Anyone can suggest me?

[This is example picture of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNbHw.png)

Comment: The font you are using only supports the English thing. You need to find a font that supports the language you are targeting.

Comment: No, I use Thai font and It also support English. It can work very well in TextView. But It can't work in EditText like the example picture.

Comment: Ah I see, I think it has something todo with the manufacturer also of the device also.

Answer (score 0):

You must use some Unicode font that support your wanted language in the `setTypeface` method. Like [Arial Unicode MS](http://ufonts.com/download/arial-unicode-ms/197925.html).

Comment: I already tried Arial Unicode font as you told. But it still can't work.

Comment: use [this](http://www.f0nt.com/release/book-akhanake/) font buddy. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class that return EditText Object with font you want to support.

```
EditText public SetLanguage(EditText tv,string type)
{
 EditText newtv = tv;
 Typeface tf;
 switch(type)
 {
  case "en":
     tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"en.ttf");
     break;
  case "thai":
     tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"thai.ttf");
     break;
   //   up so on                

 }
   newtv.setTypeface(tf);
   return newtv;
 }

  // and call it any where..
  EditText etPlace = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  etPlace = classobj.SetLanguage(textView1,"thai");
  //assign string of text to it
```

Comment: I use Thai font for both languages and it supports ENG. So, I have to set same font for 2 cases (en/thai) right?

Comment: It depends to your font support thai and eng languages.